# Online forum software or services

Tags: forum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Forum Software should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25771/what-forum-software-should-i-use)

What forum software is out there?

I've used [PhpBB](http://www.phpbb.com/) in the past, but that was a long time ago and I'm guessing there might be better stuff out there.

My requirements are:

- registration required to post (name, email, password)
- public viewing
- some ability to customize
- needs to look reasonably good (it's not for geeks)
- hosted or self hosted
- if self hosted it needs to be PHP & MySQL
- free or paid

(I can't add tags, but I wanted to tag this "forums".)

Comment: Made CW as per: http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/212/list-of-x-questions

Comment: take a look at askbot http://askbot.org it's in python though

Answer (score 3):

I've been a happy [vBulletin](http://www.vbulletin.com/) user for years and years - if vBulletin doesn't already integrate a feature, there's a plugin for it (or you can write your own without too much difficulty).

Licensing seems to have increased in price fairly dramatically with the release of vBulletin 4.0, however, I think you'll find it's a worthwhile investment if you plan to have a busy forum.

Answer (score 3):

I've been quite happy with [Vanilla Forums](http://vanillaforums.org/) on the sites I've used it on. It's not for everyone, but I like its simplicity. It's not too hard to install or administer or customise the themes.

Answer (score 3):

[bbPress](http://bbpress.org/) from the makers of WordPress is worth a look.

Comment: Yes, I've seen a few instances of this around the web and it looks great, not as horribly bloated as phpBB and vBulletin.

Answer (score 1):

I have to stick a vote up for your old one, phpBB.

I have used it for absolutely ages with very few issues.

Answer (score 1):

I like [SMF](http://www.simplemachines.org/)

Answer (score 0):

PunBB seems good. I've tried it as a user on two sites in total. I have not hosted it.